# Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/NamedModulesPlugin'

Tags: webpack, angular8, webpack-dev-server, updating

**I updated my Angular project from Angular 2 to Angular 8 and when I update webpack 2 to webpack 5+ ,I am having this issue** ,

**Compilation Error**

***npm run start***

> Marlin@3.3.0 start D:\Marlin\Marlin_SIC\MarlinWeb(Angular_6to8_without_Wijmo)
> npm run server:dev

> Marlin@3.3.0 server:dev D:\Marlin\Marlin_SIC\MarlinWeb(Angular_6to8_without_Wijmo)

> **webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile --watch --content-base src/**

Error: **Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/NamedModulesPlugin'**

Require stack:

- D:\Marlin\Marlin_SIC\MarlinWeb(Angular_6to8_without_Wijmo)\config\webpack.dev.js
- D:\Marlin\Marlin_SIC\MarlinWeb(Angular_6to8_without_Wijmo)\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js
- D:\Marlin\Marlin_SIC\MarlinWeb(Angular_6to8_without_Wijmo)\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js

> at Function.Module._resolveFilename
> (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
> at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
> at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
> at Object. (D:\Marlin\Marlin_SIC\MarlinWeb(Angular_6to8_without_Wijmo)\config\webpack.dev.js:9:28)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
> at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
> at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
> at WEBPACK_OPTIONS (D:\Marlin\Marlin_SIC\MarlinWeb(Angular_6to8_without_Wijmo)\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:114:13)
> at requireConfig (D:\Marlin\Marlin_SIC\MarlinWeb(Angular_6to8_without_Wijmo)\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:116:6)
> at D:\Marlin\Marlin_SIC\MarlinWeb(Angular_6to8_without_Wijmo)\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:123:17
>
> ```
> at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
> at module.exports (D:\Marlin\Marlin_SIC\MarlinWeb(Angular_6to8_without_Wijmo)\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:121:15)
> at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Marlin\Marlin_SIC\MarlinWeb(Angular_6to8_without_Wijmo)\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js:84:40)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12) npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR!
> ```
>
> errno 1 npm ERR! Marlin@3.3.0 server:dev: `webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile --watch --content-base src/` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the
> Marlin@3.3.0 server:dev script. npm ERR! This is probably not a
> problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\usama.attique\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-10-26T06_12_44_783Z-debug.log
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! Marlin@3.3.0 start:
> `npm run server:dev` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed
> at the Marlin@3.3.0 start script. npm ERR! This is probably not a
> problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\usama.attique\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-10-26T06_12_44_873Z-debug.log
> PS D:\Marlin\Marlin_SIC\MarlinWeb(Angular_6to8_without_Wijmo)>

**{package.json}**

**"scripts"**: {

```
"install": "napa",
"build:dev": "webpack --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile",
"build:prod": "webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js  --progress --profile --bail",
"build": "npm run build:dev",
"ci": "npm run lint && npm test && npm run e2e",
"clean:dist": "npm run rimraf -- dist",
"clean:install": "npm set progress=false && npm install",
"clean:start": "npm start",
"clean": "npm cache clean && npm run rimraf -- node_modules dist",
"github-deploy:dev": "webpack --config config/webpack.github-deploy.js --progress --profile --github-dev",
"github-deploy:prod": "webpack --config config/webpack.github-deploy.js --progress --profile --github-prod",
"lint": "npm run tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
"postversion": "git push && git push --tags",
"prebuild:dev": "npm run clean:dist",
"prebuild:prod": "npm run clean:dist",
"preclean:install": "npm run clean",
"preclean:start": "npm run clean",
"preversion": "npm test",
"rimraf": "rimraf",
"server:dev:hmr": "npm run server:dev -- --inline --hot",
"server:dev": "webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile --watch --content-base src/",
"server:prod": "http-server dist --cors",
"server": "npm run server:dev",
"start:hmr": "npm run server:dev:hmr",
"start": "npm run server:dev",
"tslint": "tslint",
"typedoc": "typedoc",
"version": "npm run build",
"watch:dev:hmr": "npm run watch:dev -- --hot",
"watch:dev": "npm run build:dev -- --watch",
"watch:prod": "npm run build:prod -- --watch",
"watch:test": "npm run test -- --auto-watch --no-single-run",
"watch": "npm run watch:dev",
"webpack-dev-server": "webpack-dev-server",
"webpack": "webpack"
```

},

**"dependencies":** {

```
"@angular/animations": "^8.2.14",
"@angular/cli": "^8.3.29",
"@angular/common": "^8.2.14",
"@angular/compiler": "^8.2.14",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.14",
"@angular/core": "^8.2.14",
"@angular/forms": "^8.2.14",
"@angular/http": "^6.1.10",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.14",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.14",
"@angular/platform-server": "^8.2.14",
"@angular/router": "^8.2.14",
"@angularclass/conventions-loader": "1.0.2",
"@angularclass/hmr": "1.2.1",
"@angularclass/hmr-loader": "3.0.2",
"@angularclass/request-idle-callback": "1.0.7",
"@angularclass/webpack-toolkit": "1.3.3",
"angular2-autosize": "1.0.0",
"angular2-datatable": "0.4.2",
"angular2-text-mask": "0.22.0",
"animate.css": "3.5.1",
"assets-webpack-plugin": "3.4.0",
"awesome-bootstrap-checkbox": "1.0.0-alpha.4",
"bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.4",
"bootstrap-colorpicker": "2.3.6",
"bootstrap-datepicker": "1.6.4",
"bootstrap-markdown": "2.10.0",
"bootstrap-select": "1.11.2",
"bootstrap-slider": "9.2.0",
"core-js": "2.4.1",
"d3": "3.5.17",
"dropzone": "4.3.0",
"easy-pie-chart": "2.1.7",
"font-awesome": "4.6.3",
"fullcalendar": "3.0.1",
"glyphicons-halflings": "1.9.0",
"hammerjs": "2.0.8",
"http-server": "0.9.0",
"ie-shim": "0.1.0",
"jasny-bootstrap": "3.1.3",
"jquery": "3.1.0",
"jquery-flot": "0.8.3",
"jquery-slimscroll": "1.3.8",
"jquery-sparkline": "2.3.2",
"jquery-ui": "git://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui.git#1.11.4",
"jquery.animate-number": "0.0.13",
"jszip": "^2.6.1",
"jvectormap": "2.0.4",
"jwt-decode": "^2.1.0",
"magnific-popup": "1.1.0",
"markdown": "0.5.0",
"messenger": "git+https://github.com/HubSpot/messenger.git#v1.4.2",
"moment": "2.15.1",
"morris.js": "0.5.0",
"ng2-bootstrap": "1.1.5",
"ng2-datetime": "1.2.0",
"ng2-modal": "0.0.21",
"ng2-select2": "0.5.1",
"ng2-table": "1.1.0",
"ng2-translate": "^2.5.0",
"ng2-validation": "^3.3.0",
"ng2-validators": "^1.7.0",
"nvd3": "1.8.4",
"pace": "git://github.com/HubSpot/pace.git#v0.7.7",
"parsleyjs": "2.4.4",
"rickshaw": "1.6.0-rc.0",
"rxjs": "^5.2.0",
"select2": "4.0.3",
"select2-bootstrap-theme": "0.1.0-beta.9",
"shufflejs": "4.0.2",
"socket.io-client": "^1.7.2",
"webpack-raphael": "2.1.4",
"webpack-subresource-integrity": "^1.5.2",
"widgster": "0.0.3",
"wijmo": "node_modules/wijmo/NpmImages/wijmo-amd",
"zone.js": "0.6.25"
```

},

**"devDependencies"**: {

```
"@types/core-js": "^2.5.3",
"@types/hammerjs": "2.0.33",
"@types/jasmine": "2.2.34",
"@types/node": "^12.12.6",
"@types/source-map": "0.1.27",
"@types/uglify-js": "2.0.27",
"@types/webpack": "1.12.34",
"angular2-template-loader": "0.5.0",
"awesome-typescript-loader": "^2.2.4",
"codelyzer": "0.0.28",
"copy-webpack-plugin": "3.0.1",
"css-loader": "0.25.0",
"exports-loader": "0.6.3",
"expose-loader": "0.7.1",
"file-loader": "0.9.0",
"html-webpack-plugin": "2.21.0",
"imports-loader": "0.6.5",
"istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "0.2.0",
"json-loader": "0.5.4",
"metrojs": "0.9.77",
"napa": "2.3.0",
"node-sass": "3.9.3",
"parse5": "1.3.2",
"raw-loader": "0.5.1",
"rimraf": "2.5.2",
"sass-loader": "4.0.2",
"script-loader": "^0.7.0",
"source-map-loader": "0.1.5",
"string-replace-loader": "1.0.5",
"style-loader": "0.13.1",
"to-string-loader": "1.1.4",
"ts-helpers": "1.1.1",
"ts-loader": "^9.2.6",
"ts-node": "1.3.0",
"tslint": "3.15.1",
"tslint-loader": "2.1.3",
"typedoc": "0.4.5",
"typescript": "^3.7.5",
"url-loader": "0.5.7",
"webpack": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
"webpack-dev-middleware": "^5.0.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
"webpack-md5-hash": "0.0.5",
"webpack-merge": "^5.8.0"
```

},